# How to add units to EditText with numberDecimal inputType?

Tags: android

Is it possible in Android to implement such an EditText? numberDecimal inputType prevents me from doing this.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be implement using java code like this `edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);`